# ideone api for android showing Auth Error always

Tags: android

I want to set up my own online compiler. I want to use Ideone Api for this. But its api is available but it always shows this exception "Auth error" I tried very hard but could find any tutorial on how to Resolve it 
please help me are any ideone webservices example  available send me

Answer (score 0):

you may have to use your Ideone username and the password (API password)...not specifying that could be the only problem causing "Auth error"......